# How to combine two different media query in jquery

Tags: jquery

Please see below code for jquery and help me to minimize code. So I expect two different media queries combine in a one line.

jquery

```
$('.navbar-close').click(function(){
    $('.navbar').animate({'height':'0'});
    if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 479px)').matches){
        $('body').css({'overflow':'auto'});
    }
    if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 767px)').matches){
        $('body').css({'overflow':'auto'});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done simply as we do in CSS like:

```
if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 479px), (max-width: 767px)').matches){
    $('body').css({'overflow':'auto'});
}
```

From Media queries [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#(comma)):

> **`,` (comma)**
>
> Commas are used to combine multiple media queries into a single rule. Each query in a comma-separated list is treated separately from the others. Thus, if any of the queries in a list is true, the entire media statement returns true. In other words, lists behave like a logical or operator.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. It works.